# How to give a cell containing with 'ISREF' a default value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use a formula that uses INDEX function. In order to generalize for all the lines that sometimes may contain information from another sheet and sometimes they may not.

That's why I get an `ISREF` error within the cells because the corresponding cells in the other sheet can't be referenced.

I want to display a default value instead of the `ISREF` error message. I tried using `ISREF` function itself within an `IF` condition but it doesn't work on the same cell. It only references another cell because it is a cell checking function and it doesn't check the output of a formula.

I tried also `ISERROR` function but it didn't work also. Here's a snippet of the formula that I am putting within my cell:'

```
INDEX(Plagesuivi; $Q203; 9)
```

- Plagesuivi is a named range
- $Q203 contains the row number (that I fetch dynamically and correctly)
- 9 is the column number

P.S. The indexing is working fine with cells that do appear is the named range: Plagesuivi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error the best way to avoid all sorts of errors is:

```
= IF($Q203=""; 0; IFERROR(INDEX(Plagesuivi; $Q203; 9); 0))
```

- `IFERROR` checks for all sorts of unpredictable errrors it is a safe-guard against unpredicted cases where it takes 0 by default.
- `IF` in the second case checks whether the referencing content of Q203 is empty or not, in case it is empty the cell takes 0 by default else it gets the output of the false case formula.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with iferror() like this:

```
=iferror(INDEX(Plagesuivi;$Q203;9);0)
```

Or replace the 0 with ""

Comment: I just wrapped it within a condition and it worked fine. = SI($Q203="";0;SIERREUR(INDEX(Plagesuivi; $Q203; 9); 0)) I am working for a french client that is why the condition is in french formula. Problem solved thank you.

Comment: @haddagart good, glad it works.